# How to add item to drop-down menu of hold action on text

Tags: android-studio

I have no clue how to interact with the drop-down menu of the hold action outside the app

For example, when I press and hold on a word anywhere, there will be a drop-down menu to choose whether to copy, paste or cut it. I wish to add an item to add the word to my app or paste the word from my app.

No code can be provided.

I wish to know some keywords or examples which can do similar stuff.

Comment: You want a drop-down and on click of it some action should be performed!

Comment: is it possible to write an app to add item in the drop-down list of the highlighted text?